# Prove the sequence, $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

Prove that if $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below, for all n, $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$ and there exists $M$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}, M\leq x_n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \inf\{x_n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Do you guys agree with my proof? Thanks!

Proof: Let M be the greatest lower bound of the sequence $x_n$. Then $x_n \geq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $k$ such that $x_k > M - \epsilon$.

Since the sequence $x_n$ is monotone and decreasing, $M-\epsilon > x_k \geq x_{k+1} \geq x_{k+2} \geq \dots \geq M$ and equivalent to $M-\epsilon > x_n > M+ \epsilon$ for all $n\leq k$. Therefore, $|x_n - M|<\epsilon$ for all $n\leq k$. Thus, the sequence $x_n$ is convergent and converges to M. So, the $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = M$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \inf\{x_n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer below, you went wrong with $M-\epsilon$. A different point is that you shouldn't call the glb $M$. You are given $M$ as a lower bound (but not the glb). So you should call the glb something else, like $M_0$.

Comment: hello @almagest thank you for the response. Do you agree with this? Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $M+\epsilon>M$ and therefore $M+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound of $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. Thus, $x_N<M+\epsilon$, for some $N\in\mathbb N$. Since the real sequence is monotonic and decreasing, $n\geq N$ implies $x_n<M+\epsilon$ too. So $n\geq N$ implies $x_n\in[M,M+\varepsilon)$ implies$\lvert x_n-M\rvert<\epsilon.$

Comment: You are still using $M$, when it already means something else! Use $M_0$ for the greatest lower bound. Otherwise ok, except that you need to add at the end something like "which establishes that $x_n\to M_0$ as $n\to\infty$".

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @almagest which M should be the initial M? I am sort of confused, sorry

Comment: The question tells you that there exists a lower bound $M$. Note that $M$ is merely a lower it is **not** the greatest lower bound. You then start your proof by setting $M$ to be the greatest lower bound. That is confusing and guaranteed to lose marks. Yes, the set is bounded below, so it has a greatest lower bound. But you need to call that greatest lower bound something different from $M$. Call it $K$ if you like. But **not** $M$!

Comment: I see what you mean, how about this? Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $M_0+\epsilon>M$ and therefore $M_0+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound of $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. Thus, $x_N<M_0+\epsilon$, for some $N\in\mathbb N$. Since the real sequence is monotonic and decreasing, $n\geq N$ implies $x_n<M_0+\epsilon$ too. So $n\geq N$ implies $x_n\in[M_0,M_0+\epsilon)$ implies$\lvert x_n-M_0\rvert<\epsilon.$ Thus, establishing that $x_n$ converges to $M_0$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: It should be $M_0+\epsilon>M_0$ and therefore ... [Reason: Because $M_0$ is the greatest lower bound, so $M_0+\epsilon$ cannot be a lower bound, meaning that we can find **some** $x_N$ below it ...] You do not need to put in the part in  [ ]. I am just explaining why you need $M_0$ not $M$. Otherwise excellent!

Comment: @almagest brilliant, thank you for all your time and help with this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proof is not correct. Since $\varepsilon>0$, you clearly cannot have $M-\varepsilon>M$.

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then $M+\varepsilon>M$ and therefore $M+\varepsilon$ is *not* a lower bound of $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. Therefore, $x_N<M+\varepsilon$, for some $N\in\mathbb N$. Since the sequence is monotonic and decreasing, $n\geqslant N\implies x_n<N+\varepsilon$ too. So$$n\geqslant N\implies x_n\in[M,M+\varepsilon)\implies\lvert x_n-M\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Hey jose, thank you for the response. This is what i said, I think it needs to be M + epsilon at the second to last line but I am not sure,

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $M+\epsilon>M$ and therefore $M+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound of $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. Thus, $x_N<M+\epsilon$, for some $N\in\mathbb N$. Since the real sequence is monotonic and decreasing, $n\geq N$ implies $x_n<M+\epsilon$ too. So $n\geq N$ implies $x_n\in[M,M+\varepsilon)$ implies$\lvert x_n-M\rvert<\epsilon.$